# Move trash icon to bar with function icons

Tags: gnome-shell, trash, ubuntu-dock

Love the new version, but can the "trash" receptacle icon be moved to the bar with the rest of the function icons? This would clean up an otherwise beautiful desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Is the "bar" the top bar? Look for extensions then.

Maybe this -> https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/48/trash/

[image]